# Trouble launching my first Ruby on Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have taken the entire set of code and put it on my server, but it doesn't work. The pages do not load following the URLs.

I want to launch my Ruby on Rails application on a hosted service like mochahost or godaddy.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting error messages? What do the logs say?

Comment: Im getting a 404 error when trying to access the mysite.com\articles directory.  Usually it would prompt me for a password then let me see the page, but instead it's just a 404

Comment: Do any other page are working/accessible?

Comment: What messages do you get from the web server? Look in the server's log files. It would be helpful to post them, and perhaps the URL that doesn't work. Say, the customary localhost server listens on port 3000. Are you specifying the port in the URL?

Comment: on port :3000, the message is that "google chrome cannot connect to the mysite:3000"

Comment: When I try to access the page, the log file states "[Sat Apr 26 08:33:53 2014] [error] [client 58.13.7.0] File does not exist: /home/aaaa/public_html/mysite.com/articles"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have just copied all the files over and that's it? I'm sorry to tell you this but this is not PHP :-)

Rails uses an application server to handle requests. Your file structure is irrelevant to the request (that's what the config/routes.rb is for).

I guess you take a look at this page: [RubyOnRails deployment](http://rubyonrails.org/deploy)

Further reading: [Application server @ wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_server)

Answer (score 1):

If you are totally new to rails, I highly suggest using a service like Heroku over traditional shared hosting.  I am not too far ahead of you in learning rails but I can say with 100% certainty that I would not want the added hassle of managing my own rails server environment at this stage.

Check out Michael Hartl's book if you haven't already.  http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book It will walk you through a Heroku setup and deployment.

Also, did I mention Heroku is free until you scale up?  Perfect for learning!

Comment: +1 - You can also create a CNAME record on your domain so your URL will bring up the Heroku app